# How to send an SMS from a web server written in PHP? using Betamax url

Tags: php, sms

Betamax offers link to send sms , how to convert this links to php plus html form to send sms.

Using HTML SMSlink
You can also send text messages (SMS) without using our software or accessing the website. Use the following link and fill in the desired data:

https://www.poivy.com/myaccount/sendsms.php?username=xxxxxxxxxx&password=xxxxxxxxxx&from=xxxxxxxxxx&to=xxxxxxxxxx&text=xxxxxxxxxx

Explanation of the variables:

username: your poivY username
password: your poivY password
from: your username or your verified phone number. Always use international format for the number starting with +, for instance +491701234567
to: the number you wish to send the sms to. Always use international format starting with +, for instance +491701234567
text: the message you want to send

Comment: ok, but. what's your question?

Comment: `file_get_contents`, curl, or something like Guzzle can all be used to make HTTP requests. It's kinda terrifying that your vendor has you pass username/password to them at all, let alone as GET params, though.

Comment: The answer is clear , this itl have variables like name pass etc i want to make aphp file with those variables plus an html file for the simple form where tu put user pass id ... and send btn will open the sendsms.php

Comment: so the "question" is do it all for me, well that wont fly here on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the service provider, just use the phone number and the service provider email, it's a back-end way to the world of SMS.

Check it out: [Email Service Providers for Texting Through Email](https://20somethingfinance.com/how-to-send-text-messages-sms-via-email-for-free/)

Use the HTML form for user info:

```
<p>Enter the Service Provider and the phone number to send a text right now!!</p>
<form action="current page or another, depending on structure" onsubmit="alert('Sent, it should be received shortly...');" method="post">
    <select name="inputMobileServiceProvider" required>
        <!--These are just some of them-->
        <option value="Verizon">Verizon</option>
        <option value="ATT">AT&T</option>
        <option value="TMobile">T-Mobile</option>
        <option value="Sprint">Sprint</option>
    </select>
    <input type="tel" name="inputMobileNumber" required />
    <input type="text" name="inputSubject" placeholder="Subject..." />
    <textarea name="inputMessage" required></textarea>
    <button>Send!!</button>
</form>
```

And the PHP, whether it be on any page:

```
<?php
    $inputServiceProvider = $_POST['inputMobileServiceProvider'];
    $inputMobileNumber = $_POST['inputMobileNumber'];
    $inputSubject = $_POST['inputSubject'];
    $inputMessage = $_POST['inputMessage'];

    if ($inputServiceProvider === "Verizon") {
        $serviceProvider = "@vtext.com";
    } elseif ($inputServiceProvider === "ATT") {
        $serviceProvider = "@txt.att.net";
    } elseif ($inputServiceProvider === "TMobile") {
        $serviceProvider = "@tmomail.net";
    } elseif ($inputServiceProvider === "Sprint") {
        $serviceProvider = "@messaging.sprintpcs.com";
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('I\'m sorry but a Service Provider wasn't found, please try again!')</script>";
    }
    $searchArray = array(" ", "-", "(", ")", "+1")
    $inputMobileNumber = str_ireplace($searchArray, "", $inputMobileNumber);
    $recipientEmail = $inputMobileNumber + $serviceProvider
    mail($recipientEmail, $inputSubject, $inputMessage);
?>
```

And remember, this is just an example. For production-use, use `htmlspecialchars()` and other security measures on the website. Also, make sure that there is a spam control. Your website might be in trouble if you mess with random SMS numbers, or if a user is spamming others.

Comment: this is not what the OP is asking, he wants to use a specific SMS provider: https://www.poivy.com/

Comment: @IdontDownVote I was just giving ideas, ways to less complicate it.

Comment: this is a Q&A site, answers should actually match the question.

Comment: @HaythamDalank No Problem!!